# Page freezes after data is populated in AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a auto-complete search bar(implemented with [angularjs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)) that suggests a list of schools and clicking one item takes me to a ui-state `/home/:id`.

However, the page freezes when the school data is populated after a search is done. The search bar is not longer functional, nor does the page scrolls.

For the time being I am reloading the page everytime a search is done. This get the page working, but this is definitely not the solution.

Here is the router code:

```
.state('home.search', {
    url: '/search',
    templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
    data : { title: 'Home', theme: { primary: 'grey-50', folded: 'true'} },
    resolve: load('views/home/home.js'),
})
.state('home.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    templateUrl: 'views/home/detail.html',
    data : { title: 'Home', theme: { primary: 'grey-50', folded: 'true'} },
    resolve: load('views/home/home.js'),
})
```

And here is the controller code:

```
 function selectedItemChange(item) {
     $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
     window.location.reload(); 
     self.selectedSchool = item;
     $state.transitionTo('home.detail', {id: item.schoolCode}, $stateParams, { 
        reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true
    });
 }
```

The controller code: `window.location.reload();` makes the code work. But this is not the solution. If I remove that code, the page populates with the new school data, but it freezes completely. Can anybody suggest why this is happenning? And what is the solution to this?

Comment: what is the amount of data you bring? is it too big, to the browser? it can be the reason browser gets unresponsive

Comment: I presume that controller code is not part of home.search or home.detail?

Comment: @TarangRathod No man. I am sure the amount of data is not the problem. I have tried with very tiny data. Still the page freezes.

Comment: @rrd This controller code is part of home.detail. This code is executed when a suggestion is clicked in the search bar.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle/plnkr for reproduction?